# Printing bigger number in NASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, min

I'm just starting learning assembly and i've encountered a little problem. I'm trying to code a program which takes two integers and prints the bigger one. I want to do this using printf and scanf from C. Unfortunately what I wrote always returns the second value and I keep wondering why. Here's the code:

```
extern printf
extern scanf
global main

section .text
main:
push rbp
                    ;input of the first number
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, number1
    xor rax, rax
    call scanf

                    ;input of the second number
    mov rdi, fmt
    mov rsi, number2
    xor rax, rax
    call scanf

                    ;comparing numbers
    mov rdx, qword [number1]
    cmp rdx, qword [number2]
    jl _1isSmaller
    jge _2isSmaller

_1isSmaller:            ;1st number is smaller
    mov rdi, fmt_out
    mov rsi, qword [number1]
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    jmp _exit


_2isSmaller:            ;2nd number is smaller
    mov rdi, fmt_out
    mov rsi, qword [number2]
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    jmp _exit


_exit:

pop rbp

mov rax, 0
mov rbx, 1
int 80h

section .data
fmt db "%d", 0
fmt_out db "Smaller number: %d", 10, 0
number1 dd 0
number2 dd 0
```

Is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined your numbers (`number1` and `number2`) as `DWORD`s with `dd` in the `.data`-section, but you're referencing them as `QWORD`s with `cmp`.

So the result is quite unpredictable/depending on the memory layout.

Comment: But if I change the qword to dword then it crashes saying "error: mismatch in operand sizes". What should I do in this case?

Comment: My suggestion is to change `mov rdx, qword [number1]` to `mov edx, dword [number1]` and `cmp rdx, qword [number2]` to `cmp edx, dword [number2]`. That should fix the "operand size mismatch error".

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zumalo: I don't write an explicit operand-size when there's a register operand that implies a size.  e.g. `mov edx, [number1]`.  You only need a `dword` or `qword` or whatever when the other operand is an immediate (or it's a one-operand instruction like `inc`).